# How can I get the same object type as a result of using mapply to a similar function

Tags: r

I get on the simple function an object which I can use to reconstruct or plot while on the same function when applying mapply I can not get an object but the components result of the function.

```
library(wmtsa)

x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

# Now normal-results in an object I could use to plot or reconstruct. 

D <- wavDWT(x, n.level= 5, wavelet= "s2")
D

# Now different results than above as per using mapply on the same function.

wavelet <- wavelet<- c("d2","s2","d4","s4","d6")
nlevel <- seq(1: as.integer (floor (logb ((length(x)),base=2))))
ex2  <-  expand.grid(n.levels = nlevel, wavelet=wavelet, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
D <- mapply(function(y,z)  wavDWT(x, n.level= y, wavelet= z), ex2$n.level, ex2$wavelet)

# Desired Output result of using regular function is "wavTransform" object 

D

Discrete Wavelet Transform of x
-------------------------------
Wavelet                  : s2 
Length of series         : 36 
Number of levels         : 5 
Boundary correction rule : periodic 
Filtering technique      : convolution 
Zero phase shifted       : FALSE 
Crystals                 : d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 s5 extra
```

How could I obtain the same object type in DWT result of using mapply as in simple function result D.

Comment: I don't understand what the desired output is either. I think you just want to set `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` in `mapply()` or just swap `Map()` for `mapply()`. I'm not sure what you're talking about with the `lapply` comments at the end since there is no `lapply` above.

Comment: Appologies Desired Output is the result of object D, the lapply was edited by another person for mapply I re edited again

Comment: What is "D" object? I don't understand what do you want. By the way you wrote `lapply` in your post, not `mapply`.

Comment: You want to run the command multiple times so you're going to need a collection of some sort. You can't get exactly the same class back but you can get a list of objects of that class back maybe. Again, if you change `mapply` to `Map`, that will prevent conversion to array and will give you a list and you can check the class with `class(DWT[[1]])` for the first item in the list.

Comment: @MrFlick - thank you for your answer. However the fact that I have to apply it over 30K makes this very cumbersome I think.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You can easily apply functions to every item in a list. Exactly what do you think will be more difficult with such a structure?

Comment: @MrFlick - appologies I may have interpreted your answer possibly wrong. Though you sugested running multiple times the function over new variables. Could you kindly let me know what you mean in runnig the command multiple times.

Comment: I suggested running `DWT <- Map(function(y,z)  wavDWT(x, n.level= y, wavelet= z), ex2$n.levels, ex2$wavelet)` which will return a list where each element will be an object the same class as `D` where the parameters correspond to the different rows of `ex2`.

Comment: @MrFlick - Done it and it works, thank you, it seems MAP has some amazing properties, I had not used it before. I think you should answer it as not to leave the question unanswered. Or if you authorize me I will take your answer and placed it in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default, `mapply()` tries to simplify the result to a matrix if possible. In this case that is not desireable. You can either use the `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` parameter, or just use `Map()`. For example

```
DWT <- Map(function(y,z) wavDWT(x, n.level= y, wavelet= z), ex2$n.levels, ex2$wavelet)
```

This will return a list. Each item in the list will be the same class as the original `D`. You can verify this with

```
class(D) == class(DWT[[1]])
```